# PubSub javascript library between browser windows

Tags: javascript, dom-events, publish-subscribe, observer-pattern

Do you know whether any of the existing **PubSub** libraries offers the possibility to communicate between windows? As examples where it can be used:

- Communication between a popup window (open with window.open) and the opener
- Communication between an iframe and the container page
- Communication between extension pages of a google chrome extension.

Comment: between iframe and main doc would be simple enough assuming same domain. between windows not available yet

Comment: You say "simple enough" for iframe and main doc. Do you know such a library? The ideea was to not implement another library.

Comment: from main document is easy to access elements of iframe ( same domain only) so implementing pub/sub would be same as if there is no iframe. Give example of what you want pub/sub to do. Can create a very simple pub/sub using jQUery custom events even

Comment: Did you consider `postMessage`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a way to communicate between browser windows, but if you get the server involved, you could create a web socket between each of the pages and the server, and the server could proxy methods between them.  Libraries such as socket.io (node) or SignalR (asp.net) can abstract away much of the plumbing.

Comment: No. Server is not involved. I am interested only to run it on the client, since is UI logic.

Comment: WebRTC has limited peer-to-peer communication but I believe the server still does the initial hand-off.  https://labs.ericsson.com/blog/a-web-rtc-tutorial and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/ seem descent starting places.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of libraries out there for pub/sub type interactions.

Here's some candidates from my recent research:

- Jim Cowart's [postal.js](http://github.com/postaljs/postal.js) with the postal.xframe plugin.
- Ben Alman's [postMessage](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/)
- easyXDM.net

I'm not sure how they match your examples, but they all handle the iFrame issue. easyXDM is primarily interested in cross domain calls, so may work in all scenarios.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For pubsub functionality in Chrome extensions I wrote the chromeps library:
https://github.com/anderspitman/chromeps